# lapply + ggplot cant fill my boxplot. (No colors-filling in boxplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply, boxplot

Today I was working on a dataset with 26 numeric variables and I wanted to see if I could brew some data to get a boxplot for each of my class groups, in a column in my dataset, for each of my variables.

So, first I created an example to see if it works:

```
ggplot(dford, aes(y= c(let.7g.5p), x=clase, fill=clase)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "red", "pink", "blue", "lightblue"))
```

And everything was perfect. I got my boxplot by class, with color so I can distinguish better my classes. *Just perfect*

But when i try to make a function so I can input a list of my column names so I can automate it, i get it to work, but it doesn't apply any color. I got my boxplots, with the same data, but just in plain white.

```
varlist <- names_mirna

customPlot <- function(varName) {

  ggplot(dford, aes_string(dford$clase,varName), fill=dford$clase) + 
    ## Fill doesn't seem to work. My X in aes does.
      geom_boxplot()
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "red", "pink", "blue", "lightblue"))

 ## Not working also.
}

lapply(varlist, customPlot)
```

Is there something wrong with my code? I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Nothing wrong with color to brighten up the plot, but technically, you don't really need different colors here because, well, that's what the x-axis labels are for. But if you had _another_ variable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the mapping to the fill aesthetic in `aes_string`. Using `mtcars` as example, try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

varlist <- c("mpg", "hp")

mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)

customPlot <- function(varName) {

  ggplot(mtcars, aes_string("cyl", varName, fill = "cyl")) +
    geom_boxplot() 

}
lapply(varlist, customPlot)
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```r
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>